# Spring Security OAuth2 Not Working Without JWT

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I'm trying to implement the OAuth2 example from the [Spring Security and Angular JS](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_sso_with_oauth2_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_v) tutorial, but I am having an issue getting it working without JWT. The code for the example can be found [here](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/tree/master/oauth2).

I have made the following modifications to the example to attempt to get it working without JWT.

**/resource/src/main/resources/application.properties**

```
server.port: 9998
server.contextPath: /resource
logging.level.org.springframework.security: DEBUG
#spring.oauth2.resource.jwt.keyValue: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnGp/Q5lh0P8nPL21oMMrt2RrkT9AW5jgYwLfSUnJVc9G6uR3cXRRDCjHqWU5WYwivcF180A6CWp/ireQFFBNowgc5XaA0kPpzEtgsA5YsNX7iSnUibB004iBTfU9hZ2Rbsc8cWqynT0RyN4TP1RYVSeVKvMQk4GT1r7JCEC+TNu1ELmbNwMQyzKjsfBXyIOCFU/E94ktvsTZUHF4Oq44DBylCDsS1k7/sfZC2G5EU7Oz0mhG8+Uz6MSEQHtoIi6mc8u64Rwi3Z3tscuWG2ShtsUFuNSAFNkY7LkLn+/hxLCu2bNISMaESa8dG22CIMuIeRLVcAmEWEWH5EEforTg+QIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Commented out the property for the jwt keyValue.

**/ui/src/main/resources/application.yml**

```
security:
  user:
    password: none
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize
      clientId: acme
      clientSecret: acmesecret
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
#      jwt:
#        keyValue: |
#          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
#          #MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnGp/Q5lh0P8nPL21oMMrt2RrkT9AW5jgYwLfSUnJVc9G6uR3cXRRDCjHqWU5WYwivcF180A6CWp/ireQFFBNowgc5XaA0kPpzEtgsA5YsNX7iSnUibB004iBTfU9hZ2Rbsc8cWqynT0RyN4TP1RYVSeVKvMQk4GT1r7JCEC+TNu1ELmbNwMQyzKjsfBXyIOCFU/E94ktvsTZUHF4Oq44DBylCDsS1k7/sfZC2G5EU7Oz0mhG8+Uz6MSEQHtoIi6mc8u64Rwi3Z3tscuWG2ShtsUFuNSAFNkY7LkLn+/hxLCu2bNISMaESa8dG22CIMuIeRLVcAmEWEWH5EEforTg+QIDAQAB
#          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
zuul:
  routes:
    resource:
      path: /resource/**
      url: http://localhost:9000/resource
    user:
      path: /user/**
      url: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

Commented out the jwt property and replaced with:

```
userInfoUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
```

**/authserver/src/main/java/demo/AuthserverApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthserverApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    @ResponseBody
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access").setViewName("authorize");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthserverApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(-20)
    protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

//        @Bean
//        public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
//            JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
//            KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
//                    new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "foobar".toCharArray())
//                    .getKeyPair("test");
//            converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
//            return converter;
//        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("acme")
                    .secret("acmesecret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token",
                            "password").scopes("openid");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
//            .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
                throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess(
                    "isAuthenticated()");
        }

    }
}
```

Commented out the `jwtAccessTokenConverter()` method and removed it from `configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)`.

When I try running the application it works fine up until the point where I have to authorize "acme" access to protected resources. When I click Approve I get a 401 and an error page that says "Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token".

This is caused by the POST request to http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize which fails and then redirects to http://localhost:8080/login?error=access_denied&error_description=User%20denied%20access&state=lsb7Ik

Here are the following logs from the API Gateway and the OAuth2 servers.

**API Gateway Application**

```
2015-11-19 12:04:24.561 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error=access_denied&error_description=User%20denied%20access&state=ksNKYy at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.561 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error=access_denied&error_description=User%20denied%20access&state=ksNKYy at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.561 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2015-11-19 12:04:24.561 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@6b29d520. A new one will be created.
2015-11-19 12:04:24.561 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error=access_denied&error_description=User%20denied%20access&state=ksNKYy at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.561 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@24905eb7
2015-11-19 12:04:24.561 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error=access_denied&error_description=User%20denied%20access&state=ksNKYy at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.561 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error=access_denied&error_description=User%20denied%20access&state=ksNKYy at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfHeaderFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.562 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error=access_denied&error_description=User%20denied%20access&state=ksNKYy at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.562 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.562 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login?error=access_denied&error_description=User%20denied%20access&state=ksNKYy at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.562 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Request is to process authentication
2015-11-19 12:04:24.564 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Encoding and sending form: {response_type=[code], client_id=[acme], scope=[null], state=[ksNKYy], redirect_uri=[http://localhost:8080/login]}
2015-11-19 12:04:24.571  WARN 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : POST request for "http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize" resulted in 403 (Forbidden); invoking error handler
2015-11-19 12:04:24.575 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token
2015-11-19 12:04:24.575 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
2015-11-19 12:04:24.575 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler@489090b4
2015-11-19 12:04:24.575 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .a.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler : No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error
2015-11-19 12:04:24.575 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2015-11-19 12:04:24.575 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2015-11-19 12:04:24.576 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Looking up handler method for path /error
2015-11-19 12:04:24.577 DEBUG 41956 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Did not find handler method for [/error]
```

**OAuth2 Application**

```
2015-11-19 12:04:24.546 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.546 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.546 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@fb75c5f1: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fb75c5f1: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@36ebcb: Username: user; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@21a2c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 010CF170666FD7398D2E42E4431924B1; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@335f832b
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/logout'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/login'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fb75c5f1: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@36ebcb: Username: user; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@21a2c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 010CF170666FD7398D2E42E4431924B1; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/authorize; Attributes: [authenticated]
2015-11-19 12:04:24.547 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fb75c5f1: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@36ebcb: Username: user; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@21a2c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 010CF170666FD7398D2E42E4431924B1; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER
2015-11-19 12:04:24.548 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@54fdd60d, returned: 1
2015-11-19 12:04:24.548 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2015-11-19 12:04:24.548 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2015-11-19 12:04:24.548 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2015-11-19 12:04:24.549 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /oauth/authorize
2015-11-19 12:04:24.550 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.View org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)]
2015-11-19 12:04:24.552 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2015-11-19 12:04:24.553 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2015-11-19 12:04:24.567 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/css/**'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.567 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/js/**'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/images/**'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/authorize'; against '/error'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@335f832b
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2015-11-19 12:04:24.568 DEBUG 41954 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I suspected it was failing because of the "Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize" on the OAuth server, but after disabling csrf protection in the http security the same error still exists. Not sure why CSRF would be the problem after removing JWT from the equation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I know this is not a solution, but I've been spending lots of time debugging this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219911/why-is-accesstokenrequests-preservedstate-perpetually-null-with-a-resultant-csr At present I suspect that a new instance of DefaultOAuth2ClientContext gets created when the service provider redirects back to the client - but this may not be the intention.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it was that I haven't set context path to `/uaa` for the auth server. My suggestion is to start from identical copy of 'Spring Security and Angular JS' and then move in small steps towards your custom solution. After each step, run examples and see whether everything still works. This way you can easily catch what caused problem.