# Flutter login with Spring have oauth2

Tags: spring, flutter, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

In my case, I have a Flutter mobile app and backend as Spring boot. In Spring I have set up an oauth2 so that the user can log in by email.

The login by email feature works fine in the browser with the URL "/oauth2/authorization/google". But now from my mobile app, I don't know how to allow the user to log in with emal.

Do you know how to solve this one? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found the answer to this topic. I implement like in this issue [Solution Spring Backend OAuth2 Client for both web apps as for native (mobile) apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62261091/solution-spring-backend-oauth2-client-for-both-web-apps-as-for-native-mobile-a) and adding some custom code to retrieve the Spring access token after the login process of OAuth2 web application in the browser then store the token in my flutter app. Hope it helps in your case.